# How generate r.js using node dist.js

Tags: node.js, requirejs, r.js

In the requireJS site they said that We can generate the r.js using

```
 "node dist.js"
```

Source http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

for me it does make error :

```
node git:(develop) ✗ node dist.js 

fs.js:549   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                     ^

    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'build/jslib/x.js'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mtaboubi/www/capsana-portal/webapp/unified-portal/src/main/webapp/node/dist.js:21:19)
        at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
        at startup (node.js:117:18)
```

Any help ? thank you

Comment: That's weird .. your error appears in `fs.js`. Are you running this on a fresh clone of the github repo [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js)? I just ran the command and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the meaning of fresh clone ? and no I'm not using a github repo ...

Comment: The repository that I'm using is local (not related to github)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like there might an error in your version of `dist.js` / `fs.js`.

Could you try running `node dist.js` on the original version of the r.js repository [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js)?

- If that works, then you'll have to do further troubleshooting on your `r.js` file to get to the bottom of the issue.
- Otherwise, it's an issue with your development environment, in which case you can post the errors here.

Comment: I meant an error in your version of `dist.js` / `fs.js` .. follow the instructions in the answer and report your results